# Search in Graylog for "[error]"

Tags: graylog

I have some trouble with searching in the Graylog Webinterface:

Currently i have the following query:

```
message: "\[error\]"
```

But the query returns also messages like this:

```
 [warn] Error while parsing: %MatchError
```

Any idea how to search for all entries beginning with "[error]" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to create a custom Elasticsearch index mapping and use another analyzer for the `message` field if you want to include special characters such as `[` or `]` in your queries.

References:

- http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.3/pages/configuration/elasticsearch.html#custom-index-mappings
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/analysis-analyzers.html